# Variant of DES and breaking the 16 round DES

Tags: des

Consider a variant of DES algorithm, called DES-WEAK. In DES-WEAK,
there is no permutation P in a round and all the S-boxes are replaced. The new S-boxes are all
identical and defined as follows. Let b0, . . ., b5 represent the six input bits to an S-box and a0,
a1, a2, and a3 the four output bits. Then, a0 = b3 ⊕ b0b1b5, a1 = b0 ⊕ b1b3b5, a2 = b1 ⊕ b2b3b5,
and a3 = b2 ⊕ b4 ⊕ b1b3b5.
• Design an algorithm to break 16-round DES-WEAK as efficiently as possible.

We have approached this design like the way I have mentioned below..

> We use differential cryptanalysis to recover the key. Consider the
> differ- ential 000100 going into the S-box S2. Let one of the two
> inputs with the given differential

> be b0b1b2b3b4b5 and the corresponding output be a0a1a2a3. Let the
> output for second input (= b0b1b2b2(b3 ⊕ 1)b4b5) be a 0 0 a 0 1 a 0 2
> a 0 3 . Then, a0 ⊕ a 0 0 = 1, a1 ⊕ a 0 1 = b1b5, a2 ⊕ a 0 2 = b2b5
>
> and a3 ⊕ a 0 3 = b1b5. Hence the output differential is 1000 on the
> given input differential with
>
> probability 1 2 + 1 2 · 1 4 = 5 8 (either b5 is zero or b5 is one and
> both b1, b2 are zero).
>
> The problem with this differential output is that, in the next round,
> after expansion, two S-boxes will get non-zero differential. Assume
> that, in the first round, the differential into S1 is 000000 and the
> left half differential is also all zeroes. Then, in the next round,
> differential into S1 would be 000001 and into S2 would be 010000. Let
> us analyze both. First consider S1. With the same notation for first
> input and the two outputs (now the second input is b0b1b2b3b4(b5 ⊕
> 1)), we get a0 ⊕ a 0 0 = b0b1, a1 ⊕ a 0 1 = b1b3, a2 ⊕ a 0 2 = b2b3
> and a3 ⊕ a 0 3 = b1b3. Hence the output
>
> diffrential is 0000 with probability 1 2 · 3 4 + 1 2 · 1 4 = 1 2
> (either b3 is zero and one of b0, b1 is zero or
>
> b3 is one and both b1, b2 are zero). Consider S2. Now the second input
> is b0(b1 ⊕ 1)b2b3b4b5, and so we get a0 ⊕ a 0 0 = b0b5,
>
> a1 ⊕ a 0 1 = b3b5, a2 ⊕ a 0 2 = 1 and a3 ⊕ a 0 3 = b3b5. Hence the
> output diffrential is 0010 with
>
> probability 1 2 + 1 2 · 1 4 = 5 8 (either b5 is zero or b5 is one and
> both b0, b3 are zero). In the next round, after applying expansion,
> the differential into these two S-boxes becomes 000000 000100 which is
> exactly the same differential that went into the first round into
> these two! Using this analysis, we can now derive a charecteristic
> with high probability as follows. Let Z stand for zero differential on
> 32 bits, P stand for differential 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
> 0000
>
> , and Pˆ stand for differential
>
> 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>
> . The above analysis shows the following transformation sequence of
> differentials: [P, Z] p=1 −−→ [Z, P] p= 5 8 −−−→ [P, Pˆ] p= 5 16 −−−→
> [P , Z ˆ ] p=1 −−→ [Z, Pˆ] p= 5 16 −−−→ [P , P ˆ ] p= 5 8 −−−→ [P, Z].
>
> The overall probability of the above charecteristic is 5 4 2 14 .
> Iterating this once again, and then taking only the first two rounds
> of this, we get a fourteen round charecteristic with probability 5 9 2
> 31 ≈ 9 × 10−4
>
> . Hence using a few thousand plaintext pairs, DES-WEAK can be broken.

Now we have a new challenge and are stuck in it. The below mentioned design is a slight modification of the above mentioned question that we have worked upon. The design goes as follows..

> Consider a variant of DES algorithm in which all the S-boxes are
> replaced. The new S-boxes are all identical and defined as follows.
> Let b1, b2, · · · , b6 represent the six input bits to an S-box. Its
> output is b1 ⊕(b2 · b3 · b4), (b3 · b4 · b5) ⊕ b6, b1 ⊕ (b4 · b5 ·
> b2), (b5 · b2 · b3) ⊕ b6. Here ‘⊕’ is bitwise XOR operation, and ‘·’
> is bitwise multiplication. Design an algorithm to break 16-round DES
> with new S-boxes as efficiently as possible.

In this design the permutation operation is still present and S-box output is different. So how can we approach this like the one we have done above, given that the Permutation Box is still there.

Comment: If you want anyone to read this in detail, please format your equations properly, you have dots where I assume there should be divisions, since the quantities are probabilities.

Comment: Note that this seems to be an assignment, so according to our policies, please provide hints in comments (or the answer box, if that's not feasible) instead of complete answers.